# Yii2: Kartik's DetailView & Select2 not loading saved values

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, detailview

I use Kartik's DetailView and Select2 to save a list of multiselected attendants out of a dropdown. In form:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'attendants')->widget(Select2::classname(), ['data' => $model->attendantList, 'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Select...'), 'multiple' => true]]) ?>
```

In view:

```
[
           'attribute' => 'attendants',
           'format' => 'raw',
           'type' => DetailView::INPUT_SELECT2,
           'widgetOptions' => ['data' => $model->attendantList, 'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Select...'),'multiple' => true]],
           'value' => call_user_func(function($model){
                                  $attendants = '';
                                  foreach($model->persons as $person) {$attendants .= Html::a($person->name, ['aux-person-event/index', 'person_id' => $person->id]).'<br/>';}
                                  return $attendants;
                            }, $model),
        ],
```

Where `$model->attendantList` is an array of 'id' & 'name' pairs.

If I use standard ActiveForm through update action, saved values load normally into form on update. However they're not when using Kartik's DetailView in edit mode.

Any clue?

Comment: Are you sure that attendants variable is defined in your model? did you mentioned it in rules section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, as @Jigar7521 pointed out, it turns that I was using an attribute not defined in model as existant in my DB although it was defined in rules section. Nice tip. Thanks.